# gdb with Python support in cross-compile development

Tags: python, c++, gdb, qt5, qt-creator

I cross-compiled Qt5.9.2 for RPi2. On the target I've installed `gbdserver` and `gdb-python2` packages. I can debug my executables manually launching gdb.

From the development machine, instead, QtCreator refuses to debug because:

> The selected build of GDB does not support Python scripting

I'm not sure if the gdb that it's talking about is the one on the target machine or on the sysroot of the host. I'm using the linaro toolchain (armhf) and it seems it doesn't have the Python support.

Is there a way to debug within QtCreator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to run QtCreator on Windows?

There's a solution that worked for me (Windows). Download GDB with python, prebuild by Qt [here](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/prebuilt/gdb/). I got this solution on [this](https://wiki.qt.io/QtCreator_Build_Gdb) Qt tutorial.

On Linux you can try to use gdb-multiarch or try the same solution that I get.

After you download the sources, just point to it on QtCreator Debugger